# Why my unit tests fail unless I use the debug flag?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

If I execute my tests like this:

```
mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js
```

They fail with:

```
  1)  "before all" hook: before:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

If I add the `--debug` flag, everything works...

```
mocha --debug test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js
```

Every test executes and passes. How come? Where can I dig to find a culprit?

```
node -v
v0.12.2

mocha --version
2.2.5
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Paste the first test that fails